# Why are OF and CF flags set in this case when using IMUL r/m8 instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, flags, carryflag

When using **IMUL** instruction with a single 8-bit operand, the result is stored in **AX** register.
I have the following code

```
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0

    mov al, 48
    mov bl, 4

    call dumpregs

    imul bl

    call dumpregs
```

**48 * 8 is 192(C0 in hex)**, which is correctly stored in **AX** register as **00C0**(see the output below). The signed range of **AX** register is **-32,768 to +32,767**, and unsigned range is **0 to 65,535**. Therefore both the OF and CF flag should be clear(0). But as you can see in the following output, they both are set(1).

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: According to https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul *“The CF and OF flags are set when the signed integer value of the intermediate product differs from the sign extended operand-size-truncated product, otherwise the CF and OF flags are cleared.”*

Comment: The logic being that the result will always fit in the double size destination so using flags for that would be pointless. This way the flags tell you if the result can be safely truncated to the original source operand size, in this case 8 bits. Since 192 does not fit in signed 8 bits, the flags are set. In other words it overflowed the 8 bit size so you need to use the full 16 bit output produced.

Comment: Ok, so the OF is set because because 192 doesn't fit in signed 8-bits. But, why is CF set? I know that CF is set when the unsigned value is out of range, but for 8-bit 255 is the maximum range, and 192 is under that range, so CF should be clear, but it's not, why??

Comment: CF and OF in multiplication operations are always being set/reset in parallel, as specified in the doc mentioned by @PaulR

Comment: And why is AL taken into consideration when setting AL, when the whole AX flag is the destination.

Comment: @vitsoft why are they set in parallel? The logic for both flags is different.

Comment: Because **Intel decided so**. The *logic* concerns arithmetic operations (add, sub) only. Carry Flag does not mean *unsigned overflow* in other instructions, such as shifts, rotations, multiplications.